# C# await of Task is endless

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm trying to use following async extention method:

```
public static async Task<MyClass<T>> ToMyClass<T>(this Task<T> source)
{
    \\ some logic
    return new MyClass<T>(await source);
}
```

by writing this test method:

```
public async void Test()
{
    Task<int> task = new Task<int>(() => 10);
    var result = await task.ToMyClass();
    task.Start();
    Assert.True(result.Value == 10);
}
```

But all I've got is infinite waiting. I have tried remove await keyword, apply it to task like this `(await task).ToMyClass()`, but it leaded me only to infinite waiting or exceptions.
When I changed usage of `task` to Task.Run method:

```
var result = await Task.Run(() => 10).ToMyClass();
```

everything worked well. 
What am I doing wrong while using constructor and `Start()` method? And what is the difference beetween these two ways?

Comment: `new Task()` returns a task that is not started. You then await it. You are then starting it, so you are aware that it was not started. Yet, you are awaiting that task that is not started, which will obviously never end because the task is not running. On contrary, `Task.Run` returns a started task.

Comment: Yeah, your code is essentially "when my task is done running, start it", which of course isn't really gonna work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of differences here.

As @GSerg has mentioned in the comment, the `Task` constructors are a bit special because they create a "cold" task that doesn't run until you explicitly start it with the `Start` method. Relevant info from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#task-status):

> Tasks that are created by the public Task constructors are referred to as cold tasks, because they begin their life cycle in the non-scheduled Created state and are scheduled only when Start is called on these instances.

With that explanation, it becomes obvious why you're waiting infinitely: because you're waiting on something that hasn't started yet, and so is never going to complete.

So if you swap the order of your `task.Start();`  and `var result = await task.ToMyClass();` lines, starting the task before waiting on it, that should solve the infinite wait issue:

```
public async void Test()
{
    Task<int> task = new Task<int>(() => 10);
    task.Start();
    var result = await task.ToMyClass();
    Assert.True(result.Value == 10);
}
```

Note that while `Task.Run` gives you a "hot"(started) task, which doesn't have that problem, it also has a different effect, in that it schedules whatever you pass to it to a Thread Pool thread (not a good idea server-side like ASP.NET), whereas Tasks, in general, [don't necessarily involve threads](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Answer (score 0):

So, you try to wait before start.

```
 var result = await task.ToMyClass();
 task.Start();
```

You should start it before awaiting